# Null pointer Exception is coming for Initialized object in JUnit

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito, easymock

I have below implementation of classes.. 'EmpAddress' is an interface & 'EmployeeInterfaceFactory' is a class which has static method 'getAddressImpl' that provides EmpAddress Implemented class Object... I have JUnit method as below where I am getting Null Pointer Exception... Need help/suggestion in implementing this JUnit...

```
***************************************************************************
public class Employee(){

private Address address = new Address();

public String getEmployeeDetails(){
  String details = address.getDetails();
  return details;
}
}
***************************************************************************
public Address address(){

private EmpAddress empAddress = EmployeeInterfaceFactory.getAddressImpl();

public String getDetails(){

String details = empAddress.getEmpDetails();  // Null pointer exception coming here
return details;
}
}
****************************************************
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({EmployeeInterfaceFactory.class})
public class EmployeeTest(){

Employee emp;
EmpAddress empAddress;

@Before
public void setUp(){
 emp = new Employee();
 empAddress = createMock(EmpAddress.class);
 mockStatic(EmployeeInterfaceFactory.class);
}

@Test
public void getEmployeeDetailsTest(){
  expect(EmployeeInterfaceFactory.getAddressImpl()).andReturn(empAddress);
  expect(empAddress.getEmpDetails()).adnReturn("testing data");

  String result = emp.getEmployeeDetails();
}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: nope, no where JUnit implementation is available. I can't change the code.. Is there any way to mock those lines to make JUnit pass ?

Comment: @Balaji211 please post the stacktrace so that we can debug it properly.

Answer (score 0):

check if you are getting empAdress at line `private EmpAddress empAddress = EmployeeInterfaceFactory.getAddressImpl();`, may be you can move it to `setUp` method, call `setUp` in `getDetails` method, so that empAdress is not null when you are trying to access it in `getDetails`

and in TestCase, you are returning empAddress, which is not yet initialized,  which is causing null pointer
`expect(EmployeeInterfaceFactory.getAddressImpl()).andReturn(empAddress);`

Comment: "EmployeeInterfaceFactory" is in different package/dependency.. which I don't have control. Code change is not possible...

Comment: empAddress=createMock(EmpAddress.class); is present in @Before method.. Is it not enough.. Please clarify